# How to convert this birth date into age in Node js with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Node js Express with Mongoose. In the front-end there are bday bmonth and byear fields for registration. However I want to convert that data into age and save it separately in back-end in user model as age.

**function**

```
module.exports = {
  async CreateUser(req, res) {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
      username: Joi.string()
        .required(),
      email: Joi.string()
        .email()
        .required(),
      password: Joi.string()
        .required(),
        bday: Joi.number().integer()
        .required().min(2).max(2),
        bmonth: Joi.number().integer()
        .required().min(2).max(2),
        byear: Joi.number().integer()
        .required() 
    });

    const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
    if (error && error.details) {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
    }

    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
    if (userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email already exist' });
    }

    const userName = await User.findOne({
      username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username)
    });
    if (userName) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Username already exist' });
    }

    return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
      }
      const body = {
        username: Helpers.firstUpper(value.username),
        email: Helpers.lowerCase(value.email),
        bday: (value.bday),
         bmonth: (value.month),
       byear: (value.month),
        password: hash
      };
      User.create(body)
        .then(user => {
          const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
            expiresIn: '5h'
          });
          res.cookie('auth', token);
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    });
  },
```

**Model**

```
username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  password: { type: String },
   bday: { type: String },
  bmonth: { type: String },
  byear: { type: String },
  age: { type: String },
```

I thought that there is a way that can be used function in the model instantly and calculate age from birth date or convert it inside above function but have no idea how to achieve to that result?
How to get age from those 3 details (bday, bmonth,byear)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `Date` object with the provided data and calculate the age :

```
/**
 * Date from day / month / year
 *
 * @param day    The day of the date
 * @param month  The month of the date
 * @param year   The year of the date
 */
function dateFromDayMonthYear( day, month, year ) {
    return new Date( year, month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}

/**
 * Get the years from now
 *
 * @param date  The date to get the years from now
 */
function yearsFromNow( date ) {
    return (new Date() - date) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;
}

/**
 * Gets the age of a person
 *
 * @param birthDate  The date when the person was born
 */
function age( birthDate ) {
    return Math.floor( yearsFromNow( birthDate ) );
}

console.log( age( dateFromDayMonthYear( 7, 12, 2008 ) ) ); // 10
console.log( age( dateFromDayMonthYear( 17, 12, 2008 ) ) ); // 9
```

Keep in mind that you might want to do `dateFromDayMonthYear( parseInt( day ), parseInt( month ), parseInt( year ) )`, since your initial values are string.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.  In which part should I implement this code in my example? In model or I should add new age in const schema user with joi validations  and attach that function to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = new Date()
console.log(date)
console.log(date.getMonth() + 1)
console.log(date.getDate())
console.log(date.getFullYear())

Output:
2018-12-08T16:46:12.274Z
12
8
2018
```

So you use those and find the age by substracting.

How it works in Node.js :

```
You fetch a user by ID.
  currentUser= User.findOne({userID})
you get currentUser's info like this: userDay=currentUser.bday,userMonth=currentUser.bmonth,userYear=currentUser.byear
```

Rest is not specific to Node.js or mongoose, so lot of examples available online :)

Comment: I am a beginner in Node js so this looks confusing, can you please show how it works on my code?

Comment: Yes but it's not converting into age.

Comment: @fernandod I could post full code, but why don't you search for a program to calculate age from birthdate? There are many right here on stackoverflow. You have the day,month and year of birth, you have current day,month and year. It is easy.