# How to convert these 3 values together into age?

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

We have 3 values separately birthday birthmonth and birthyear since in the front end each input is separate. In the back-end where I use node js we want to get age from these 3 details. we found such a usage of moment js in here: `moment().diff(moment('20170507', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'years')`
But my code is a bit different for using such a result.

```
module.exports = {
  async CreateUser(req, res) {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
      username: Joi.string()
        .required(),
      email: Joi.string()
        .email()
        .required(),
      password: Joi.string()
        .required(),
        birthday: Joi.number().integer()
        .required().min(2).max(2),
        birthmonth: Joi.number().integer()
        .required().min(2).max(2),
        birthyear: Joi.number().integer()
        .required() 
    });

    const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
    if (error && error.details) {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
    }

    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
    if (userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email already exist' });
    }

    const userName = await User.findOne({
      username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username)
    });
    if (userName) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Username already exist' });
    }

    return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
      }
     const age = moment().diff(moment([year, month - 1, day]), 'years');
      const body = {
        username: Helpers.firstUpper(value.username),
        email: Helpers.lowerCase(value.email),
        birthday: (value.bday),
         birthmonth: (value.month),
       birthyear: (value.month),
        password: hash,
       age:age
      };
      User.create(body)
        .then(user => {
          const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
            expiresIn: '5h'
          });
          res.cookie('auth', token);
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    });
  },
```

How can we use moment for the above unique case to convert these 3 values into age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
const age = moment().diff(moment([year, month - 1, day]), 'years');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying should it look like this? I've included it in my above code. your answer above the const body. and inside body added just: age:age

Comment: You would like to substitute `year`, `month` and `day` with the real variables containing those values.

Comment: Which in your case are `value.year`, `value.month` and `value.bday`

Comment: You can also achive this without moment ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686540/1282674 )

Comment: Sami I 've changed these 3 variables as they are but it says byear is not defined when I submit the form. And shows under the variable inside the line which you provided. I set byear, bmonth and bday as they are the names of variables.

Comment: whenever I replaced it it shows error under first byear
(moment([byear, bmonth - 1, bday]), 'years')

Comment: @drinchev I checked your code as well but again facing the same issue as with moment js it says byear, bday, bmonth are undefined.

Comment: @NewTechLover I believe either your schema is wrong, or the values you should use for calculating the age are `value.birthday`, `value.birthmonth` and `value. birthyear`.